# Any() con un array de string devuelve resultados erróneos en C#

Tags: c#, array, linq, ienumerable, any

Esta evaluación del contenido de un array de strings con Any() no funciona:

```
string comando = "kandy";
if(new string[] { "c", "caja" }.Any(comando.Contains)) Console.WriteLine("Por Caja");
if(new string[] { "k", "kandy" }.Any(comando.Contains)) Console.WriteLine("Por Kandy");
if(new string[] { "d", "doc" ,"documento" }.Any(comando.Contains)) Console.WriteLine("Documento");
```

deberia devolver "Por Kandy" pero devuelve 2 resultados:

```
 Por Kandy
 Por Documento
```

y si comando = "doc" devuelve

```
 Por Caja
 Por Documento
```

No logro entender donde esta la falla, la comparacion son palabras separadas del string, Contains compara cada item del array, porque coinciden palabras que no tienen relacion?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque existen 2 funciones `Contains`

- Una que aplica a Listas y Arrays
- Otra que aplica a String

Tu usas la segunda

Vamos por partes:

Tenemos `string comando = "kandy";`

1.- `new string[] { "c", "caja" }.Any(comando.Contains)` Esto evalua

- kandy contiene una `c` -> NO
- kandy contiene un `caja` -> NO

2.- `new string[] { "K", "kandy" }.Any(comando.Contains)` Esto evalua

- kandy contiene una `k` -> SI y no sigo preguntando porque `Any` busca hasta que encuentra la primera condición que cumpla

3.- `new string[] { "d", "doc" ,"documento" }.Any(comando.Contains)` Esto evalua

- kandy contiene una `d` -> SI, en Kan**d**y; y tampoco sigo preguntando.

---

A mi me da la impresión que tu quieres hacer esto

```
string comando = "kandy";
if (new string[] { "c", "caja" }.Contains(comando)) Console.WriteLine("Por Caja");
if (new string[] { "k", "kandy" }.Contains(comando)) Console.WriteLine("Por Kandy");
if (new string[] { "d", "doc", "documento" }.Contains(comando)) Console.WriteLine("Documento");
```

Que es equivalente (el mismo resultado) que esto:

```
string comando = "kandy";
if (new string[] { "c", "caja" }.Any(a=> a == comando)) Console.WriteLine("Por Caja");
if (new string[] { "k", "kandy" }.Any(a => a == comando)) Console.WriteLine("Por Kandy");
if (new string[] { "d", "doc", "documento" }.Any(a => a == comando)) Console.WriteLine("Documento");
```

O quizas, algo más legible como

```
string comando = "kandy";
if (comando is ['c', ..]) Console.WriteLine("Por Caja"); //Que comience con c
if (comando is ['k', ..]) Console.WriteLine("Por Kandy");//Que comience con k
if (comando is ['d', ..]) Console.WriteLine("Documento");//Que comience con d
```

Comment: Perfecto, me confundí con Contains que busca substrings y no palabras sueltas del array. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en cómo utilizas el predicado en el método `Any()`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string comando = "kandy";
        var lista = new string[] { "c", "caja" }; 
        bool exist = lista.Any(x => x.Contains(comando));       
        if(exist) Console.WriteLine("Por Caja");
        if(new string[] { "k", "kandy" }.Any(x => x.Contains(comando))) Console.WriteLine("Por Kandy");
        if(new string[] { "d", "doc" ,"documento" }.Any(x => x.Contains(comando))) Console.WriteLine("Documento");
    }
}
```

Lectura sugerida: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
string comando = "kandy";

if(new string[] { "c", "caja" }.Any(x => x.Contains(comando))) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Por Caja");
}
if(new string[] { "k", "kandy" }.Any(x => x.Conatains(comando)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Por Kandy");
}
if(new string[] { "d", "doc" ,"documento" }.Any(x => x.Contains(comando))) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Documento");
}
```

Debes utilizar correctamente el **método Any** el cual se utiliza para ver si en tu colección existe al menos un elemento que cumple con determinada condición.

**Nota**: Para hacer uso del **método Any** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta instrucción:

```
[].Any(comando.Contains)
```

Es equivalente a esta:

```
[].Any(elemento => comando.Contains(elemento))
```

Por eso al evaluar `new string[] { "d", "doc" ,"documento" }.Any(comando.Contains)`, lo evalúa como verdadero porque encuentra que `"Kandy"` contiene a `"d"`.

La solución es cambiar la función de filtrado:

```
if(new string[] { "d", "doc" ,"documento" }.Any(x => x.Contains(comando))) Console.WriteLine("Documento");
```